# How to dynamically load and use vanilla/jQuery libraries with ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, requirejs

I have a few jQuery-based JavaScript libraries I use in other projects which I'd like to use with my ExtJS project. Other projects commonly load these libraries dynamically via RequireJS:

```
define(['lib/api/client', 'lib/my_lib'], function(ApiClient, MyLib) {
  ...
});
```

Let's say I want to use these libraries in my ExtJS project. Is there a "standard" way to do this in ExtJS, or should I just rig my own solution, like this? What is the common approach to this problem?

```
require([
  'lib/extjs/ext-all',
  'lib/api/client',
  'lib/my_lib'
], function(Ext, ApiClient, MyLib) {

  Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    appFolder: 'app',
    launch: function() {
      var apiClient = new ApiClient();

      Ext.create('MyApp.view.Main', {
        apiClient: apiClient
      });

      MyLib.doSomething();
    }
  });

});
```

And

```
require(['lib/extjs/ext-all'], function(Ext) {
  Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    ...
  });
});
```

Bottom line: I want to avoid having a ton of script tags in the head:

```
<head>

<script src="lib/api/client" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/my_lib" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/my_other_lib" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/another_lib" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/and_another_lib" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/and_yet_another_lib" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
```

And I want dependency management.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Ext.Loader.loadScript method ([api](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-loadScript)). You can organize your code like this:

```
Ext.Loader.loadScript('lib/api/client');
Ext.Loader.loadScript('lib/my_lib');

Ext.onReady(function () {
     // setup your Ext JS app here, external libraries are loaded.  
});
```

Comment: I like this more than script tags in the head. However, it would be nice to have dependency management -- e.g., say that my_lib depends on my_other_lib, and ensure my_other_lib loads first.